What is the raised triangle on the left side of the Garmin G1000?

Looking at one of the official Pilot's Guides shows what looks like could be indicator LEDs inside it, but it doesn't appear to be referenced.... Not that I could find.

Link to Cessna Nav III Pilot's Guide

If you have the plane can you point your phone camera at it and see if you can see purple lights? Then it maybe some sort of proximity sensor

IrDA Port
The maintanence manual explains that in the display diagnostics page, one of the items is

IRDA―Indicates status of GDU 104X IrDA infrared port. Used for Garmin testing, it is not activated at this time

That would be the only thing that looks like an IR port on the display, and its non-use is why it's not mentioned anywhere.
It was envisioned a PDA would be used to exchange flight plans and other data through the port. The G1000 brochure dated 2003 states

The Garmin GDU 1040/1045 is the standard
control/display platform for the G1000’s primary
flight display (PFD) and multi-function display
(MFD)... It’s also
equipped with an infrared port to accommodate
data entry via handheld Garmin PDAs.


I received a response from Garmin Aviation Support:
"Thank you for contacting Garmin International. I believe this is a marker beacon that contains indicator lights for outer, middle, and inner lights.
Best Regards,
[name redacted]
Garmin Aviation Support"
I cannot find anything to corroborate this statement in your manual or elsewhere online. If anyone using a G1000 wants to check this out while flying it could help close this case.

Yes, I saw those, and I know those are not this triangle. I thought perhaps the little triangle can also flash different colors for a marker beacon. But more likely the rep who replied either didn't understand my question or doesn't know.

@codenoob yeah they definitely did not understand.

Okey doke, well I tried. Maybe someone else can shoot support a message and see if they get a more knowledgeable rep (aviation.support@garmin.com)
